# Can I make my QT GUI programs run after completely removing unity desktop?

Tags: kde, programming, qt

Can I make my QT GUI programs run after completely removing unity desktop? I am building a desktop environment on QT. How can I run my program without unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity isn't a dependency of QT apps in any way that I know of. If your question is "How can I launch a program without Unity?" The answer is this: I wouldn't uninstall Unity at all because you don't need to. First press CTL-ALT-F1. Log in, and type `xinit -- :1`. Now, with the X Terminal, you can start you window manager (for example metacity) and anything else you want. To make sure you always have a working XTerm, remember to use `&` after commands.

Basically, this just creates a new X screen, and you can switch back to your main screen with CTL-ALT-F7. To go back to your new X screen, press CTL-ALT-F8. You can create up to 6 X screens at a time, each one corresponding to F7-F12. I hope this answers your question!